# How to get the list of variable of release pipelines in Azure devops using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

I am Using Azure CLI, What I want to get the list of variable used in release pipeline .
Current I am able to get the list of variable used in build pipeline using command
***az pipelines variable List***

Please let know how can I get the list of variables used in release pipeline using CLI "through console I don't want as it is difficult to copy and paste all variable used in release pipeline"

Comment: There's no api/command available can return the release variables, the closest method is to use definitions-related api/command to get long response, and filter the response to get the info you want. But this is about how to filter the json response, which is another topic related to json/Powershell or what... So i don't talk it here.

Comment: Yes I tried have added comment you can go through the comment now the issue left for me is only how to get the variable out of the json  anyways thanks for the response you can close that question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to get the list of variable of release pipelines in Azure devops
>   using Azure CLI

There's no command available in Azure Devops CLI to list the variables of release pipeline, you have to use [az devops invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-devops-invoke) + [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the variables you want in long response.

To get release variables we can use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), let me convert it into `az devops invoke` command :

```
az devops invoke --org https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/ --area release --resource definitions --http-method Get --route-parameters project=MyProjectName definitionId=ReleaseDefinitionID --api-version 5.1 -o json
```

**More details:**

1.You should replace the MyOrgName, MyProjectName and ReleaseDefinitionID with the values on your side. And the `ReleaseDefinitionID` is something easy to find when we edit a release pipeline in web portal:

[image]

2.Since variables in release pipeline can be scoped in one stage or whole pipeline. Assuming I have `VarA:Test1` in stage1, `VarB:Test2` in stage2, and `VarC:Test3` in whole release pipeline. The response would look like this structure:

```
"variables": {
        "VarC": {
            "value": "Test3"
        }
    },
    "variableGroups": [],
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Stage 1",
            ...
            "variables": {"VarA" xxx},

            "id": 2,
            "name": "Stage 2",
            ...
            "variables": {"VarB" xxx}...
```

The variables have their different levels, please be careful with them. Hope it helps.

**Update1:**

To use `az devops` command, someone who doesn't have this extension needs to add the devops extension using something like `az extension add --name azure-devops`.

Comment: Thanks @Lance Li-MSFT for the quick response I had tried your solution and got the json file which you have shown above only one step that i had to add was :- add extension devops in my CLI  using command  **az extension add --name azure-devops**  Now for json file which i got is something messy and large to handle I mean to say that same kind of json file i can get by right clicking on the web page of azure devops where my release variable are listed and select view page source and then filter that json files based on my stages created in release pipeline  using poweshell script

Comment: @SahilKandroo Thanks for the hint, just added the command  `az extension add --name azure-devops` to my answer Update1. And since it occurs to resolve your original issue about how to get the response, you could consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442). If you're still blocked, feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same output as described by @Lance Li-MSFT can be achieved by using the following command

```
az pipelines release definition show --project YourProjectName --id YourReleaseDefinitionId
```

The stage-specific variables are in the `environments` node whereas the global variables are in the node `variables`.