# How to Get the values from json using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

Guys this is my JSON file and I want to create a PowerShell script which will give me result like
I have used method like `Get-Content` and other but there are some issues with the JSON parsing. Please find what is my requirement I have explained in details below.

```
MyLocalMachineHome
LocalMachine = Sahil_LocalMachine
Second_MyLocalMachine = Sahil_MylocalMachine
Second_MyLocalMachine = ""

Staging
Second_Staging = Sahil;_Secconf
Staging = Sahil_Staging
third_staging = stsajiii
```

There is also one functionality  which I would like to have if I want to get only variables of "staging".

I was using this function `Get-Content -Raw -Path E:\shell\Powershell\1ReleasePipelines.json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty` variables on my original JSON file but somehow there is some kind of limit in storing string which I was getting from this method.

```
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "MyLocalMachineHome",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "LocalMachine": {
          "value": "Sahil_LocalMachine"
        },
        "Second_MyLocalMachine": {
          "value": "Sahil_MylocalMachine"
        },
        "thirf_mylocal": {
          "value": ""
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Staging",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "Second_Staging": {
          "value": "Sahil;_Secconf"
        },
        "Staging": {
          "value": "Sahil_Staging"
        },
        "third_staging": {
          "value": "stsajiii"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: *there are some issues with the json parsing*. **What** issues? What have you tried? What didn't work? What error messages did you get?

Comment: The issue was actually my json files is much larger then the one I have provided  and  when I was using the method get-content which I have written above , what I was trying to put the file into a string variable like $a=get-content ... bla bla bla when I checked the value In the variable it was showing me only the values for localmachine and not for staging so I was not able to use a loop in that case that was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cls

start-transcript -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\ABC.txt'

write-output "**********Variables of Release************"

get-content -raw -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Release.json'| Convertfrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty variables 

$json = get-content -raw -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Release.json'| Convertfrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty environments

$EnvirnomentsVariables = get-content -raw -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Release.json'| Convertfrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty environments |Select -ExpandProperty name 

$ReleaseVariable = get-content -raw -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Release.json'| Convertfrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty environments |Select -ExpandProperty variables 

$i = 0 

foreach($a in $EnvirnomentsVariables)
{

    $ABC_Staging = $EnvirnomentsVariables[$i]
     #write-output $ABC_Staging
    if( $ABC_Staging -match "ABC Staging")
    {
        write-output "****************Variables of " $EnvirnomentsVariables[$i]*************"
        #add-content 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\ABC.txt' $EnvirnomentsVariables[$i] 
        # Set-content  -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Sahil.json'| ConvertTo-Json  | select $EnvirnomentsVariables[$i] 
        write-output $ReleaseVariable[$i]
        #   add-content 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\ABC.txt' $ReleaseVariable[$i] 
        # Set-content  -path 'C:\E\Devops\PowerShell_Chapters\Sahil.json'| ConvertTo-Json | select  $ReleaseVariable[$i]
    }
    $i = $i + 1   
}
stop-transcript
```

Comment: ----OutPut which i got--
**********Variables of Release************
Variablebinding      : @{value=false}
AbcPort              : @{value=100}
****************Variables of ABC Staging****************

Connection                                 : @{value=*****}    
Environment                                  : @{value=ABC Staging}    
AbcPort                                 : @{value=100    
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200427130839    Still what to change the final output but it kind of work for me

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `$json` contains your JSON content, you can do the following ugly code:

```
$environment = 'staging'
$j = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
($j.environments | where name -eq $environment).variables | Foreach-Object {
    $CurrentObject = $_
    $CurrentObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
        Select-Object -Expand Name | Foreach-Object {
            $CurrentObject.$_.value
        }
}
```

It appears your issue is that you don't know what variables are going to be contained within your JSON. So you can't easily use `Select-Object variable` or `$object.variable`. You need a dynamic approach.

---

If you know your variables ahead of time, things become simpler. You can store your variable names in an array and loop over them.

```
$variables = 'Second_Staging','Staging','third_staging'
$environment = 'staging'
$j = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonVars = ($j.environments | where name -eq $environment).variables
$variables | Foreach-Object {
    $jsonVars.$_.value
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325671/how-to-get-the-list-of-variable-of-release-pipelines-in-azure-devops-using-azure


This link might help you to understand what I want

Answer (score 0):

View all the sub-properties of variables with format-list instead of format-table.  Since the properties vary, format-table won't show all of them.  There's a lot of sloppy object construction in json.

```
$a = get-content file.json


$a.environments.variables | format-table

LocalMachine                Second_MyLocalMachine         thirf_mylocal
------------                ---------------------         -------------
@{value=Sahil_LocalMachine} @{value=Sahil_MylocalMachine} @{value=}


$a.environments.variables | format-list

LocalMachine          : @{value=Sahil_LocalMachine}
Second_MyLocalMachine : @{value=Sahil_MylocalMachine}
thirf_mylocal         : @{value=}

Second_Staging : @{value=Sahil;_Secconf}
Staging        : @{value=Sahil_Staging}
third_staging  : @{value=stsajiii}
```

Get the staging variables?

```
$a.environments | where name -eq staging | foreach variables

Second_Staging          Staging                third_staging
--------------          -------                -------------
@{value=Sahil;_Secconf} @{value=Sahil_Staging} @{value=stsajiii}
```

Comment: And what shell I add to get variable of staging and not local machine

Comment: This?  `$a.environments.variables.staging`

Comment: This?  `$a.environments | where name -eq staging | select variables`  I don't understand your question completely.